# Calculating current y-position inside list and go to next

Tags: jquery

How would I go about making my jQuery script calculate the users current y-position on my web page, which is made from 100% width&height LI's - and then go to next LI-page when you click the down-arrowkey?

The current problem is, for example, that if you start on 1, scroll past 2 and 3, and then want to click "down" to get to 4, the page jumps back to 2 because the script only calculates "$elements" position if you actually use the arrow keys.

```
var $elements = $("ol li");
var position = 0;
var moveToElement = function () {
    var elementTop = $elements.eq(position).offset().top;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").delay(0).animate({
        scrollTop: elementTop - 20
    }, 400);
}

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 38:
            // Go up
            if (position > 0) position--;
            break;
        case 40:
            // Go down
            if (position < $elements.length - 1) position++;
            break;
        default:

            return;
    }

    moveToElement();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jNc68/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use something like the following to calculate the current position of the li:

```
function setCurrentPosition() {
    var currentPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
    var li = $elements.filter(function(index) {
        if ($(this).offset().top < currentPosition) {
            position = index + 1; // not sure why i needed to add one but it seemed to work better when I did
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/jNc68/9/)

Answer (score 0):

### http://jsfiddle.net/jNc68/7/

Try this solution (not optimal code, but more for learning).

```
var $elements = $("body li");
var position = 0;
var moveToElement = function (direction) {
    var scrollTop = $elements.parent().scrollTop();

    // Find the closest element onscreen
    $elements.each(function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        var elementTop = $element.offset().top;
        if (elementTop > scrollTop) {
            // based on direction we want the previous or next element
            if (direction == -1) {
                $element = $element.prev();
            } else {
                $element = $element.next();
            }
            if ($element.length){
                // get top of new element and scroll to it
                var elementTop = $element.offset().top;
                $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").delay(0).animate({
                    scrollTop: elementTop - 20
                }, 400);
            }
            // Abort the each early
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 38:
            // Go up
            moveToElement(-1);
            break;
        case 40:
            // Go down
            moveToElement(1);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
});
```

Basically it looks for the first item visible (below scrollTop), then finds the next or previous element (based on required direction) and scrolls to it. Once you start using relative positions for the scrolling, you no longer need the index of the element.